# jsp cannot write file out of permission denial on webapps but /tmp directory?

Tags: jsp, permissions, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I have an issue regarding permission denial on file write.
The question is, I come up with this denial when I tried to write a file under webapps folder.
But, I don't have any problem with same file writing on /tmp folder.
I checked the diffrence btw those two, especially on one and each folder's permission.
The same as
drwxr-xr-x root root /tmp
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share/tomcat7-examples
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source/webapps
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source/webapps/brain03
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source/webapps/brain03/WEB-INF
drwxr-xr-x root root /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source/webapps/brain03/WEB-INF/bbs

Why can I save a file through jsp page on /tmp when not on /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source/webapps/brain03/WEB-INF/bbs?

I solved this issue anyways by "chown -R tomcat7.tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7-examples/source".
But, the mystery stands. Are there any special, hidden access control tags for each directories?

Below are the related html and jsp source code.

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=euc-kr">
        <TITLE>BBS Writing</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H2>Write here</H2>
        <FORM ACTION=BBSPost_new.jsp METHOD=POST>
            Name: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=NAME><BR>
            Title: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=TITLE><BR>
            <TEXTAREA COLS=30 ROWS=5 NAME=CONTENT></TEXTAREA><BR>
            <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE='Save'>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=euc-kr"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.util.Date"%>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("euc-kr"); 
    String name = request.getParameter("NAME");
    String title = request.getParameter("TITLE");
    String content = request.getParameter("CONTENT");
    Date date = new Date();
    Long time = date.getTime();
    String filename = time + ".txt";
    String result;
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        String filePath = application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/bbs/" + filename);
        writer = new PrintWriter(filePath);
        writer.printf("Title: %s %n", title);
        writer.printf("Writer: %s %n", name);
        writer.println(content);
        result = "SUCCESS";
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        result = "FAIL";
    }
    finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } 
    response.sendRedirect("BBSPostResult.jsp?RESULT=" + result); 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String filePath = application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/bbs/" + filename);
```

Just a guess, fact that you're trying to write /WEB-INF implies WEB-INF is at the root of your drive.